# pl/sql passing exception to a variable

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a procedure which using *execute immediate* changes a user password. If password is correct it passes a result (new password with some additional text) to OUT parameter .
The point is how to pass an error (like below) which is a result of *password verify function* to OUT parameter:

```
ORA-28003: password verification for the specified password failed
ORA-20004: Password should contain at least one digit, one character and one
punctuation
```

would you give  me  some hint/example ?

Below a code of my procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure SYS.SYSChangePassword(
  pUsername in varchar2, 
  pNewPassword in varchar2,
  pResult out varchar2(300))  as

begin
    execute immediate 'alter user '||pUsername||' identified by "' || pNewPassword || '";';
    pResult := 'New password for '|| pUsername||' has been set:  '|| pNewPassword ;
end;
/
```

Comment: With an `EXCEPTION` block, within your Pl/SQL Code. That's a way for you to raise specific exceptions, based on some logic within your code. If you put your code here, it might have `EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN ....` exception block, but for those specific ones, you need to declare a `custom_exception EXCEPTION;` and then if a certain condition is met, to `RAISE custom_exception;`. Finally, in the EXCEPTION block, you would have :`EXCEPTION WHEN custom_exception then raise_application_error(-20001, 'You custom message goes here');`. I think I exhausted it ..

Comment: @G00dy. Why not write this as an anwser?

Comment: @Rene - because I need to see a code sample, before deciding that this is indeed an answer. That's why I asked for code samples, to see if that's the thing that's missing. Either that, or this error should be passed to the OUT variable ... without code I can't give a relevant answer, I just suppose that's what's missing.

Comment: the code added ...

Comment: @Rene The point is I don't want to create "My custom message" but copy into variable exact message generated by password verify function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot specify size for an out variable `varchar2(300)` during procedure compilation.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure SYSChangePassword(
  pUsername in varchar2, 
  pNewPassword in varchar2,
  pResult out varchar2 )  as

begin
    execute immediate 'alter user '||pUsername||' identified by "' || pNewPassword || '";';
    pResult := 'New password for '|| pUsername||' has been set:  ' || pNewPassword ;

    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    pResult := SQLERRM;
end;
/
```

Now, You can call the procedure and display the error message.

```
DECLARE
vResult varchar2(400);
BEGIN
SYSChangePassword (pUsername=>'HR',pNewPassword=> 'hr',pResult=>vResult );

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(vResult);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehing like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure SYS.SYSChangePassword(
  pUsername in varchar2, 
  pNewPassword in varchar2,
  pResult out varchar2(300))  as

begin
  execute immediate 'alter user '||pUsername||' identified by "' || pNewPassword || '";';
  pResult := 'New password for '|| pUsername||' has been set:  '|| pNewPassword ;
exception
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    pResult := SQLERRM;
end;
/
```